# Allow payer to pay any other Paypal user

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I want to implement a payment gateway using PayPal for my website. My site offers members to display their products for sale. Visitors select an item and using the purchase button of Paypal would pay the owner (member of my site) of the product.
I as website owner may or may-not deduct commission (have plans to offer free service for first few months of membership).
I have been surfing Paypal developers site and other related tutorials but getting confused. What API I need to implement my above payment scenario?

P.S. I have registered a Paypal Business Account for my website. My all members will be having their Paypal accounts (i will save their Paypal id[email] in my DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Adaptive Payments API, it solves exactly what you describe:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/

Comment: Specifically, I'd look into the Preapproval and Pay API's.